# Related Rate of Angle As Base Changes

Tags: calculus, triangles, related-rates

Here's the question:
The base x of a right triangle increases at a rate of 5cm/sec, while the height remains constant at h=10. How fast is the angle θ changing when x=10cm?

What I've done so far is the following:
I know that $\frac{dx}{dt}=5$ and that I'm supposed to find dθ when x=10.

- From the triangle drawn, I can determine that $tanθ=\frac{10}{x}$
- The next thing to do would be take the derivative of both sides, and this is where I mess up. The left side should obviously be $sec^2(θ)\frac{dθ}{dt}$, and I know I should substitute x=10 and $\frac{dx}{dt}=5$, but I don't know what to do with the h or how to take the derivative of $10x^{-1}$ for this and solve it.

Comment: [How can I format mathematics here?](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation)

Comment: When you "take the derivative of both sides" the question is, the derivative with respect to what? You need to differentiate with respect to the same thing on both sides. The chain rule is your friend, get to know it really well.

Comment: @DavidK, I know that I'm taking the derivative with respect to t, time in seconds, but I'm doing it for multiple variables. I'm not sure how to do this for dh/dt or how to include dx/dt in the next step. I am familiar with the chain rule, but if you could expand on how to apply it in this context, I would really appreciate it.